# Scrapy - How to run spiders with AWS Lambda functions?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, scrapy, aws-lambda

Currently I have two small projects using Scrapy. One project is basically to scrape URL's, while the other is only to scrape products of the scrape URL's. The directory structure is this:

```
.
├── requirements.txt
├── .venv
├── url
|   ├── geckodriver
|   ├── scrapy.cfg
|   ├── url
|   |   ├── items.py
|   |   ├── middlewares.py
|   |   ├── pipelines.py
|   |   ├── settings.py
|   |   ├── spiders
|   |   |    ├── store1.py
|   |   |    ├── store2.py
|   |   |    ├── ...
├── product
|   ├── geckodriver
|   ├── scrapy.cfg
|   ├── product
|   |   ├── items.py
|   |   ├── middlewares.py
|   |   ├── ...
```

When I want to run a spider using the command, I always must follow this path: `~/search/url$ scrapy crawl store1` or `~/search/product$ scrapy crawl store1`.

How can I deploy and run this project using AWS lambda functions?

Comment: Have you looked into this? https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-from-script

Comment: What is the average run time for your spider? AWS Lambda function has a maximum invocation timeout limit of [15 minutes](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-troubleshoot-invocation-timeouts/#:~:text=Even%20though%20a%20Lambda%20function's,function%20proxy%20invocation%20to%20complete.).

Answer (score 0):

This code is a part of script used in a previous project for a client.

Just replace spider_class_getting_from_spiders with your spider class.

```
import imp
import sys
from crochet import setup, wait_for
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
from settings import *
from spiders import *


setup()
sys.modules["sqlite"] = imp.new_module("sqlite")
sys.modules["sqlite3.dbapi2"] = imp.new_module("sqlite.dbapi2")



@wait_for(900) # maximum 15 minutes 
def crawl(spider_class_getting_from_spiders):
    '''
    wait_for(Timeout = inseconds)
    change the timeout accordingly
    this function will raise crochet.TimeoutError if more than 900
    seconds elapse without an answer being received

    '''

    configure_logging({'LOG_LEVEL': 'ERROR'})
    process = CrawlerRunner(DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES);
    d = process. Crawl(spider_class_getting_from_spiders);
    return d;


def lambda_handler(event, context):

    crawl(spider_class_getting_from_spiders)
    # it return the whole event instead of return on the response to send the input to next state in the step function
    event['statusCode'] = 200
    return event
```